# How to add and remove ViewControllers from PageViewController

Tags: iphone, swift3, ios10

I have PageViewController with 3 views and I need to remove last one and add 3 more.
I know how to create working PageViewController but i don't know how to manage numbers of ViewControllers.
Is there any function like tableView.reloadData() to reload ViewControllers in PageViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation for the `UIPageViewController` [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller)

If you want to use non-native then try this : [SCPageViewController](https://cocoapods.org/?q=pageview)

If you want to use Swift Pod then try this: [EMPageViewController](https://cocoapods.org/pods/EMPageViewController)

For Native implementation:

`UIPageViewController` doesn't allow an easy way to add new view controllers one at a time, presumably because Apple wants developers to not add pages one at a time very easily (I could see this being confusing UI for users of an app).

To do what you want to do, you have to add the new view controller to an array (presumably the array of already existing view controllers, which you retrieve via "viewControllers") and then call "`setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`" with the new array of view controllers including your one (or more) new view controllers to be added to the Page View Controller.